# Function with simple partial sums of the Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let us consider function $f(x) \in C^{\infty}(-\infty, +\infty)$ that is $2\pi$-periodic on $\mathbb{R}$ (really $C^{\infty}(-\infty, +\infty)$ does not matter maybe just for simplicity). Consider its Fourier series $\displaystyle f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_k e^{ikx} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} (A_k \sin{kx} + B_k \cos{kx})$ and denote $\displaystyle f_n(x) = \sum\limits_{k=-n}^{n} a_k e^{ikx} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} (A_k \sin{kx} + B_k \cos{kx})$.

Do you know any examples of nontrivial functions $f(x)$ such that $f_n(x)$ are [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function)?

In this case "nontrivial" means that it has an infinity Fourier series. Of course for example for $\sin{x}$ or $\cos{x}$ $f_n(x)$ are elementary, but it is a degenerate case.

My attempts were in the application of the Dirichlet kernel. So $\displaystyle f_n(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x+u)\frac{\sin((n + \frac{1}{2})u)}{2\sin{\frac{u}{2}}}du$. If we can find a function for which the integral can be computed in elementary functions then we solved the problem. But I got stuck in finding such a function.

Thanks for any help or ideas!

Comment: Functions on $\mathbb R$ are not natural candidates for Fourier series unless they are $2\pi$ - periodic.

Comment: $f_n$ is allways an elementary function, since it is a finite sum of exponentials.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre, I don't know how to express it correctly, but I mean that I want $f_n$ to be "simple". Without trigonometric sums such that a number of terms depending on $n$.